# NUnit with allure integration CI/Gitlab

Tags: c#, gitlab, continuous-integration, nunit, allure

There is a project, and Nunit tests on it, with Allure connected. I can’t understand what needs to be written in .gitlab-ci.yml so that an allure report is generated (it is locally in /bin/Debug/net6.0/allure-results and the allure serve allure-results command works perfectly, but how is it do it in Gitlab, I don't understand).

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml (it runs the tests and they pass).

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
variables:
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "appsettings.test.json"
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - reports
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mkdir -p /app/Settings
    - cp "My Project/Settings/appsettings.test.json" /app/Settings
    - cd "My Project"
    - dotnet test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - My Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/allure-results/
    expire_in: 1 day
  rules:
    - when: always

allure_job:
  stage: reports
  image: frankescobar/allure-docker-service 
  script:
     - cd "My Project/bin/Debug/net6.0"
     - allure generate -c ./allure-results -o ./allure-report
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - My Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/allure-results
      - My Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/allure-report
    expire_in: 1 day
  rules:
    - when: always

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir public
    - mv "My Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/allure-report"/* public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 1 day
  rules:
    - when: always
```